# Tell ngix to send file from within node app with reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a node express app that is proxied by nginx. Nginx already handles most public static files, on **/static**

However, I have some files that need restricted access. After nginx proxies the HTTP request to my node app, on **/restricted**, I need to run my authorization logic and then, somehow, let nginx know that it should serve a specific file, from a directory that is not public.

I don't want to send the files directly from node as they are big and will block the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Generate a response from your app containing an `X-Accel-Redirect` HTTP response header which specifies a URI beginning with `/restricted/`
- Nginx will intercept the response and internally rewrite the URI
- Configure a `location` block containing an `internal` directive

For example:

```
location /restricted {
    internal;
    alias /path/to/files;
}
```

See [this document](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/) for more.